# Package manager - how to extend module with ability of module update

Tags: laravel, composer-php, package-managers, extensibility

When I use some package manager like Composer I want to use some 3rd-party module and to have an ability for example to change some views (templates) of this module, and simultaneously to have an ability to update this module trough composer. 
How can I do this?

If not - may be it is question to think about to integrate to package managers some pattern to have an ability do this well ?

Pattern - I mean some rules with that programmers will be able to show some files that will be able to be edited by consumer and to do it, developer should do some api for it by some standartized method that will be written in rules, f.e. in some composer config of his module developer will write, what files should be duplicated to userpath. After install, these files will be copied and user will be able to change it, and composer will do it able modules to see these files in users folder. And after update this user folder will not rewrite these edited files... Something like that or maybe somehow more flexibly

Answer (score 0):

How to modify views of packages installed by composer in Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages#views
Customized views should be placed in folder /resources/views/vendor/
with same names as original
This is the first place where views are searched by framework